# Blend pixels on .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, image-manipulation, alphablending, color-blending

I am trying to overlay a part of one image on top of another image on .net core (code needs to be cross platform).

I considered using ImageSharp since it supports win,mac and linux.
But i couldn't find pixel blending on their features list, although i saw that you can access an individual pixel.

So the use case would be, i have two 4k Png images and i want a small part of the first image (roughly 10% square of the overall image) to be overlayed on top of the second image (but not the whole image just the same 10% space) and get the area where the merging happened as a new Jpeg image.
(the source PNGs have some degree of transparancy).

I considered cropping out the two parts i want to merge from the two 4k images and then blending them to get the final image, but that is slow for the needs of the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

ImageSharp does support pixel blending, you can specify the pixel blending mode during Draw/Fill operations by passing in an `GraphicsOptions` parameter and setting its `BlenderMode` and `BlendPercentage`(defaults to 100%) properties.

Currently ImageSharp has implementations for the following blending modes:

- Normal
- Multiply
- Add
- Substract
- Screen
- Darken
- Lighten
- Overlay
- HardLight
- Src
- Atop
- Over
- In
- Out
- Dest
- DestAtop
- DestOver
- DestIn
- DestOut
- Clear
- Xor

Comment: Hi @tocsoft i saw those operations, but i only managed to do "Blend" on images as a whole, i want to use pixels from 2 images (a small subset) and save to a new image.


Perfomance matters to me so, that's why i wan't to blend only the needed pixels and not the whole images.|

I think you guys have a blend method that is used internally.

If you can show me an example of blending individual pixels that would be really awesomwe. Thanks for your help and your efforts on ImageSharp

Comment: you can use the `DrawImage()` api instead of the blend one and it will let you only do parts of the images.